# Load balancing and Stirling numbers of the second kind applied

Tags: combinatorics, approximation

I have, say, P threads and N > P tasks to perform using the aforementioned. I have a positive integer value associated with each tasks denoting how much work that particular task implies.

I want to partition the N tasks among P threads such that if we consider the sums of "work integers" for each thread, they would be approximately the same.

A naive but exact method for doing such "scheduling" would have to consider S(N,P) task partitions, where S(N,P) is a Stirling number of the second kind (should be impractically large in a real-world computing).

Q: Is there any good and efficient approximation algorithm for computing such "load-balanced" task partition?

Answer (score 0):

If you have only 2 processor, the problem of dividing the task into two equal task is known as the [partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). It is known to be NP-hard. So this may indicate that finding the best solution is probably a hard problem. I you only want an approximation, I would go for some kind of greedy algorithm: Assigning systematically the largest remaining task to the thread which has the less work. This will give you an easy to implement algorithm with time complexity O(number of task*number of thread).